# Install gtk in cygwin

Tags: plugins, cygwin, installation, wireshark

How can i install gtk + 2.4 or greater in cygwin. I am trying to write a plugin in wireshark. Prior to that I run the ./configure and I get the following error

```
   checking for GTK+ - version >= 2.4.0... no
   *** Could not run GTK+ test program, checking why...
   *** The test program failed to compile or link. See the file config.log for the
   *** exact error that occured. This usually means GTK+ is incorrectly installed.
   configure: error: GTK+ 2.4 or later isn't available, so Wireshark can't be compiled
```

I am running the cygwin on windows Operating system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't build Wireshark under cygwin as far as I know. To build Wireshark on Windows, follow the instructions at https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html_chunked/ChSetupWin32.html

Comment: I tried with working with Linux installed in Virtual Machine on windows. It is working fine now. Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

I believe Evan is correct. As for installing GTK+, that's one of the packages available from the normal cygwin setup. You'll want the development libraries. Looks like the package names you'll want are libgtk2.0_0 and libgtk2.0-devel to me.

On the page that Evan linked, there are instructions for building Wireshark under Cygwin. See here: https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html_chunked/ChToolsGNUChain.html.

However, it's worth pointing out that this environment is a) unsupported, and b) the instructions look to be somewhat out of date. Proceed at your own risk.